# Java tcp socket server with j2me client socket

Tags: java, sockets

I want to create java server socket and j2me client socket which can communicate with each other.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Rolled back.  Replacing the question with "Problem resolved" is not how SO works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to share data between two MIDlets running on one mobile phone?

Are you trying to exchange data between a mobile phone and a remote server?

Have you read the documentation for the javax.microedition.io package?